# session check for disable & enable checkbox C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, checkbox

I'm beginner &  I need help 
I try this code for check the id for employee to enable or disable the checkbox depend on the id for employee but the checkbox was disabled even when I login with the same Id in the session

```
if (Session["employeeNo"] == "12345") 
{
     CheckBoxList1.Enabled = true;
}

else
{
    CheckBoxList1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: What is "Session["employeeNo"] where is the result coming from

Comment: @Twyxz, from `Session` state

Comment: employeeNo is a session in the login page so when the user with the "12345" ID  login the checkbox should be enabled. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If u r using CheckBox instead of Checkboxlist ...Try this Code It will Work

```
           if (Session["employeeNo"].ToString() == "12345")
            {                  
                CheckBox1.Checked = true; // for Check
                CheckBox1.Enabled = true; // for Enable
            }
            else
            {
                CheckBox1.Checked = false; // for UnCheck
                CheckBox1.Enabled = false;  // for Disable
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Session["employeeNo"]` gives you an object, if you compare this with a string value the result will be false always. You have to convert this to string in order to compare with a string value, change the condition like this:

```
if (Session["employeeNo"].ToString() == "12345")
```